# Trying to understand the load memory address (LMA) and the binary file offset in an ARM binary image

Tags: memory, linker, arm, embedded, microcontroller

I'm working in an **ARM Cortex M4** (**STM32F4xxxx**) and I'm trying to understand how exactly the binaries (`*.elf` and `*.bin`) are built and flashed in memory, specially with regards to the memory locations. Specifically, what I don't understand is how the `LMA` gets 'translated' from the actual binary file offset. Let me explain with an example:

I have an `*.elf` file whose (relevant) sections are the following ones:(obtained from `objdump -h`)

```
my_file.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm

Sections:
Idx Name              Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text             000001c4  08010000  08010000  00020000  2**0
                      CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  1 .bootloader       00004000  08000000  08000000  00010000  2**0
                      CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
```

According to that file, the VMA and LMA are `0x8000000` and `0x8010000`, what is perfectly fine since they are defined that way in the linker script file. In addition, according to that report, the offsets of those sections are `0x10000` and `0x20000` respectively. Next, I execute the following command for dumping the memory corresponding to the `.bootloader`:

```
xxd -s 0x10000 -l 16 my_file.elf
00010000: b007 c0de b007 c0de b007 c0de b007 c0de  ................
```

Now, create the binary file to be flashed into memory:

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary --gap-fill 0xFF -S my_file.elf my_file.bin
```

According to the information provided above, and as far as I understand, the generated binary file should have the `.bootloader` section located at `0x8000000`. I understand that this is not how it actually works, inasmuch as the file would get extremely big, so the `bootloader` is placed at the beginning of the file, so the address `0x0` (check that both memory chunks are identical, even though the are at different addresses):

```
xxd -s 0x00000 -l 16 my_file.bin
00000000: b007 c0de b007 c0de b007 c0de b007 c0de  ................
```

As far as I understand, when the mentioned binary file is flashed into memory, the `bootloader` will be at address `0x0`, what is perfectly fine taking into account that the MCU in question jumps to the address `0x4` (after getting the SP from `0x0`) when it starts working, as I have checked here (page 26): https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/76/f9/c8/10/8a/33/4b/f0/DM00115714.pdf/files/DM00115714.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00115714.pdf

**Finally, my questions are:**

Will the `bootloader` actually be placed at `0x0`? If so, what's the purpose of defining the memory sectors in the linker file?

Is this because `0x0` belongs to flash memory, and when the MCU starts, all the flash is copied into `RAM` at address `0x8000000`? If so, will the `bootloader` be executed from flash memory and all the rest of the code from `RAM`?

Taking into account the above questions, if I have not understood anything, what's the relation/difference between the `LMA` and the `File offset`?

Comment: Thanks for the question! I found that building of binary images is not defined clearly in user manuals, so it was need some investigation, even digging into binutils' sources. Answer follows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, bootloader will be at 08000000, as defined in elf file.

Image will be burned in flash at that address and executed directly from there (not copied somewhere else or so).

There's somewhat undocumented behaviour, that unitialized area before actual data is skipped when producing binary image. As comment in BFDlib source states (https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=bfd/binary.c;h=37f5f9f7363e7349612cdfc8bc579369bbabbc0c;hb=HEAD#l238)

```
/* The lowest section LMA sets the virtual address of the start
   of the file.  We use this to set the file position of all the
   sections.  */
```

Lowest section (.bootloader) LMA is 08000000 in your .elf, so binary file will start at this address.
You should take this address into account and add it to file offset when determining address in the image.

```
Sections:
Idx Name              Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text             000001c4  08010000  08010000  00020000  2**0
    /*                                    ^^^^^^^^              */
    /* this section will be at offset 10000 in image            */

                      CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  1 .bootloader       00004000  08000000  08000000  00010000  2**0
    /*                                    ^^^^^^^^              */
    /* this is the lowest LMA in your case it will be used      */
    /* as a start of an image, and this section will be placed  */
    /* directly at start of the image                           */
                      CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA

Memory layout:     Bin. image layout:
000000000                    \ skipped
...       ________________   /
080000000 .bootloader         0
...       ________________
080004000   <gap>          4000
...       ________________
080010000 .text           10000
...       ________________
0800101C4                 101C4
```

That address defined in ldscript, so binary image should start at fixed location. However you should be aware of this behaviour when dealing with ldscrips and binary images.

To summarize building and flashing process:

1. When linking, start address is defined in ldscript, and and first section in elf located there.
2. When converting to binary, start address is determined from LMA and binary image starts from that address.
3. When flashing image, same address given to flasher as a parameter, so image is placed at the right place (defined in ldscript).

Update: STM32F4xxx booting process.

Address region starting at address 0 is special to those MCUs. It can be configured to map other regions, which are flash, SRAM, or system ROM. They're selected by pins `BOOTSELx`.
From CPU side it looks like second copy of flash (SRAM or system ROM) appears at address 0.

When CPU starts, it first reads initial SP from adress 0 and initial PC from address 4. Actually, reads from the flash memory are performed.
If the code is linked to run from actual flash location, then initial PC will point there. In this case execution starts at actual flash address.

```
----- Mapped area (mimics contents as flash) ---
       0:          (02001000)         ;
       4:          (0800ABCD) ----.   ; CPU reads PC here
....                              |   ; (it points to flash)
----- FLASH -----                 |
 8000000:           20001000      |   ; initial stack pointer
 8000004:           0800ABCD --.  |   ; address of _start in flash
....                           |  |   
 800ABCD: <_start:> movw ... <-'<-'   ; Code execution starts here
```

(Note: this does not apply to hex images (like intel hex or s-record) as such formats define loading address explicitly and it is used as is there).

Comment: Thanks for the complete response. But then, how is it possible that my MCU is working if, as the datasheet states, the first address to be 'exexuted' is Ox4? How can the MCU know that it must jump to 0x8000000?

Comment: I have found this post: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/346680/stm32f103-flash-memory-start-address. It seems that the STM32F4 has some sort of built-in bootloader that can be configured in several ways. According th the post, the configuration that is "start from flash" makes that internal bootloader to jump to that address. I still can't find where is that explained in the STM32F4 datasheet.

Comment: Here: https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/3d/6d/5a/66/b4/99/40/d4/DM00031020.pdf/files/DM00031020.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00031020.pdf . See boot configuration

Comment: There's asort of 'magic' called *mapping* or *aliasing*.
First of all, Section 2.4 describes boot process for several STM32F4 chips. Depending on `BOOTSEL` pins flash, internal bootloader or SRAM may be mapped to area, starting at 0. Mapped flash is your case. So really CPU starts at 0x4, which is mapped from 0x08000004.
This address contains not the code to execute, but Reset Exception Vector, which is the absolute address of the first instruction to execute.
When you link image at address 08000000 it will point somewhere in flash, and CPU simply starts execution there.

Comment: Note that the actual remapping is controlled by the MEM_MODE field of the SYSCFG_MEMRMP register, and that's where the remapping modes are documented (in the reference manual). The built-in bootloader sets this register based on the boot pins.

Comment: @starblue Yes, you're right, however this rarely need to deal with. Also, AFAIK MEM_MODE bits are set by hardware, before internal bootloader started, at least in some STM32F4's. RM0090 states those bits latched on the 4th rising edge of SYSCLK. Software barely can do it that early.

Comment: I missed that the pins are read that early, so yes, it must be done in hardware.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is pretty clear on where the the address space is for the application code for the stm32's which is 0x08000000 (a competing vendor is like 0x01000000, and so on).  And that when booting in a certain mode that 0x08000000 is mapped to address 0x00000000 as can easily be seen with a debugger (in both spaces).

The address space at 0x00000000 mapped to 0x08000000 is smaller than the potential address space at 0x08000000 depending on the chip.  So it is wise to build for and use 0x08000000 rather than 0x00000000 but for small programs you can choose either.

Because the cortex-m is a vector table machine when the logic reads address 0x00000004 which is mapped to 0x08000004 in a normal boot mode it sees 0x080xxxxx and then gets out of the 0x00000000 memory space, avoiding any limitations there.

When you use the boot0/boot1 strap pins you can instead cause 0x00000000 to map elsewhere where the burned in bootloader lives.  That bootloader of course can easily read 0x08000000 and easily simulate a reset by branching or it can change the logic and actually reset (if you ask it to, although I don't know if that bootloader actually supports running a program).  Who knows if we did work there we couldn't necessarily say.  Quite possible it always boots into the bootloader and then it changes the mapping depending on the straps.

Similar to an mmu but much simpler decoding addresses and aliasing them is pretty easy.  if boot0 == 0 and address[31:16] = 0x0000 then address[31:16]=0x0800 and the memory system decodes it at the different address, as easy as it is to write in C it is that easy in the HDL if not easier.

This is not uncommon to be found in microcontrollers as well as others, but since microcontrollers generally boot from a flash/rom but that same boot space on some architectures is also the vector or exception table that an rtos might want to manipulate sometimes you see that ram can be swapped into that space so the cpu "sees" some ram after a control register is changed where on boot it "saw" the vector table on flash.  that or you have the code on flash branch to somewhere in ram for the non-reset vector and then the rtos or any other application that cares to do this can make runtime changes to what code actually gets run for those exceptions or interrupts.

ARM imposes address space rules for where code can execute and data can live and where you might want to start your peripheral address space and what address space is reserved by arm for resources within the core.  so you will sometimes see ram have an alias at a lower address implying that if you want to run a program in ram you want to use the lower address for execution but can use either address to copy the code there.

Up to the chip designers as to how simple or complicated to make this.  For ST its pretty simple then have one or more boot pins on the package that at least let you choose between your application and the on chip bootloader, so far all the stm32s I have seen the application flash space is considered to live at 0x08000000 and is mapped/aliased to 0x00000000 for one of those boot modes.  When there are two boot pins exposed then up to four possible boot conditions can exist of which one is the application with 0x00000000 aliased to 0x08000000.

As to how to get the bits into the flash, that varies widely by tool.  The toolchains like gnu certainly will build a .bin file where the first byte of the file is the first byte from the elf that we desire to have at 0x08000000 (if built that way, if you built for 0x02000000 it will still be the first byte, and that code probably won't work).  There are tools and you can certainly write your own, that knowing that can load a .bin file at the desired place of 0x08000000 or you can have your too write to address 0x00000000 in the right mode for a program that is not too big and have it still land in the right place to execute on reset.  Likewise there are or you can write tools that can parse .elf files, intel hex, motorola srecord and others and based on the information in those binaries have the data be loaded into the address space you desire, assuming everything is bug free.

You might be trying to overcomplicate it. There isn't any magic to it, the tools need to do the sane thing and the sane thing is to take the binary from the compiler and put it in the chip where we want.  We are responsible for the linker script and such and bootstrap code/vector table of course, but if we do that right the tools if they are designed right will put the bits in the right place in the chip and if the chip is designed right as documented then it will boot and run.

> Will the bootloader actually be placed at 0x0? If so, what's the
> purpose of defining the memory sectors in the linker file?

Ideally you want your application or bootloader as you are calling it to be at address 0x08000000 in the processors address space.  In certain boot modes (boot0/boot1) that address is also aliased to 0x00000000 so you can see that vector table at both places at the same time.  If you are not in the right boot mode then only 0x08000000 will show your code.

> Is this because 0x0 belongs to flash memory, and when the MCU starts,
> all the flash is copied into RAM at address 0x8000000? If so, will the
> bootloader be executed from flash memory and all the rest of the code
> from RAM?

The logic in the chip is designed to take the address the processor puts on its address bus and have more than one address land on the application flash, the application flash is not at 0x08000000 if its a 16Kbyte flash for example its only got an address from 0x0000 to 0xFFFF when you access 0x08001234 it actually sends 0x1234 to the flash controller and or the flash controller chops the top off if it knows it is supposed to handle that request.  0x00000000, 0x08000000 are the processors view of the address space, the reality is the upper bits are decoded and route the request to whomever it belongs to and the final handler ultimately looks at the lower bits to determine what is being addressed.

Like when you deliver a letter it has a first and last name, a street address, city state zip.  Once it gets to the right post office in the right state then the street address is all that matters to the postal person.  Once it gets to the right house, often the first name is all that matters, the rest can be ignored.  No difference here.  Portions of the address (can often) become don't cares as the responsible logic that inspects that address aims the request at the correct party.

> Taking into account the above questions, if I have not understood
> anything, what's the relation/difference between the LMA and the File offset?

the elf file format is generic, way overkill for microcontroller work but being well supported and easy to use why not. The load memory address is where we the programmer have desired that code to live with respect to the processors view of the world.  From a readelf perspective the offset in the file is the offset for that information in the elf file and it is just wherever the tool put it it has no other interesting relationship. Or at least doesn't need to.  Objcopy will rip that data out of the file and for -O binary put it in a sort of memory image file with the lowest address being copied out being offset 0 in that file and the size being determined by the total address space for all of the loadable blocks (unless you use more command line parameters).

And as you sort of implied but if you think about it and have a linker script bug if you were to have even a single instruction at 0x08000000 and a single byte of .data at 0x20000000 but didn't do the AT > thing then your file despite only having three relevant bytes will be 0x20000001 - 0x08000000 bytes long.  (after a -O binary) so good idea to not put objcopy in your make file until you have debugged your linker script.  Imagine say a target where flash is 0x00000000 and memory is 0xE0000000, pretty big .bin files until you get the linker script sorted out.

Comment: Understand there is a lot of faith to this, I wouldnt use terms like magic though.  From the arms perspective there are defined addresses where things "live"  as a programmer we tell the toolchain this is where I want things, some file formats (elf, ihex, srec, etc) contain address and data information (a memory image .bin contains only data not address) and we desire the tool used to take that file on the development system and write it to flash or ram in the target  where the file asks it to be placed.

Comment: So the programmers job is to read the chip and in this case also processor documentation, tell the tools where things go, write the vector table and bootstrap correctly, and use the download tools as documented.  No bugs along the way then everything just works.