# Why nm report wrong too bigger offset value for the symbol of variable on the library written by C and embedded on golang object?

Tags: c, go, cgo, nm

I have a library which has a following variables:

```
const static volatile int64_t  head1   = 0xffffffffffffffff;
const static volatile int64_t  head2   = 0xffffffffffffffff;
const static volatile int64_t  seed = 1;
const static volatile int64_t  tail1   = 0xffffffffffffffff;
const static volatile int64_t  tail2   = 0xffffffffffffffff;
```

I've compiled it to the library file as libnantoka.a. Then linked into the go module by the cgo as follows:

```
/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L. -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread -ldl -lm -lnantoka
#include <nantoka.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
*/
import "C"
```

Then, created executable file **main** by `go build -o main main.go`

I've found the offset address of **seed** by pattern matching by binary as follows:

```
od -A x -x main | grep "0001 0000 0000 0000"
0d61f0 ffff ffff ffff ffff 0001 0000 0000 0000
```

It's seems that the offset address of symbol **seed** might be **0xd61f8**. Also, I've made sure as follows:

```sh
od -A x -x -j 0xd61e0 main | head -n4
0d61e0 7472 000a 0000 0000 ffff ffff ffff ffff
0d61f0 ffff ffff ffff ffff 0001 0000 0000 0000
0d6200 ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
0d6210 3130 3332 3534 3736 3938 3130 3332 3534
```

It indicates that 0xd61f8 must be the 64bit int with value 1, between 128bit all "f". I've be sure of that the offset address of the symbol **seed** must be **0xd61f8**.

But, the result of nm is surprisingly that:

```
nm main | grep seed
000e61f8 r seed
```

The result **e61f8** must be the offset address from the start of .rodata segment, but bigger than the real offset address from the file top!

I'm confusing why nm reports so big wrong offset? I really appreciate any suggestions from you! Thank you.

By the way, the environment is Raspberry Pi model B, go version is 1.13.5 as follows:

```sh
uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.50+ #896 Thu Jun 20 16:09:52 BST 2019 armv6l GNU/Linux

go version
go version go1.13.5 linux/arm
```

Also section infos of the main is as follows:

```
Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .interp       00000019  00010174  00010174  00000174  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  1 .note.ABI-tag 00000020  00010190  00010190  00000190  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  2 .note.go.buildid 00000064  000101b0  000101b0  000001b0  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  3 .note.gnu.build-id 00000024  00010214  00010214  00000214  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  4 .gnu.hash     00000568  00010238  00010238  00000238  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  5 .dynsym       00000b70  000107a0  000107a0  000007a0  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  6 .dynstr       00000974  00011310  00011310  00001310  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  7 .gnu.version  0000016e  00011c84  00011c84  00001c84  2**1
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  8 .gnu.version_r 000000a0  00011df4  00011df4  00001df4  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  9 .rel.dyn      00000020  00011e94  00011e94  00001e94  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 10 .rel.plt      00000368  00011eb4  00011eb4  00001eb4  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 11 .init         0000000c  0001221c  0001221c  0000221c  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 12 .plt          00000530  00012228  00012228  00002228  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 13 .text         00094338  00012758  00012758  00002758  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 14 .fini         00000008  000a6a90  000a6a90  00096a90  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 15 .rodata       0004001c  000a6a98  000a6a98  00096a98  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 16 .typelink     00000cfc  000e6ab8  000e6ab8  000d6ab8  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 17 .itablink     0000002c  000e77b4  000e77b4  000d77b4  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 18 .gopclntab    0005fd79  000e77e0  000e77e0  000d77e0  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 19 .ARM.exidx    00000008  0014755c  0014755c  0013755c  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 20 .eh_frame     00000004  00147564  00147564  00137564  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 21 .tbss         00000008  00157ee8  00157ee8  00137ee8  2**2
                  ALLOC, THREAD_LOCAL
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a dup, or not, but I think [this might be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54578360/trying-to-understand-the-load-memory-address-lma-and-the-binary-file-offset-in) - there's perhaps some load address remapping going on when you load the program. [raspberrypi.se] might also have answers?

Comment: Thank you Ken Y-N.The nm result of the original libnantoka.o written by C shows the correct offset. I wonder if the golang object has something special...